# jqueryui - mouseMove function IE condition understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, mousemove

In my jquery-ui draggable I have this -

```
....
_mouseMove: function(event) {
// IE mouseup check - mouseup happened when mouse was out of window
if ($.browser.msie && !event.button) {
    return this._mouseUp(event);
}

if (this._mouseStarted) {
    this._mouseDrag(event);
        return event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (this._mouseDistanceMet(event) && this._mouseDelayMet(event)) {
        this._mouseStarted =
            (this._mouseStart(this._mouseDownEvent, event) !== false);
        (this._mouseStarted ? this._mouseDrag(event) : this._mouseUp(event));
    }

return !this._mouseStarted;
},
....
```

Notice there is condition in the start for internet explorer. Now what is happening in my webpage is that dragging is not working for IE9 and IE10. It works for IE8, (I guess html markup errors have to do something regarding that and I am not worried about it). When I comment that condition dragging works in IE9 and IE10 i.e. I have found the fix for the problem I am facing. But as it is very high level javascript I here expecting a help from someone to explain me what is happening in the condition above.

Comment: This is why browser sniffing is bad...Versions change, different support is added and you get these problems. Also note: jQuery dropped [`$.browser`](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

Comment: yah! I knew about `$.browser`. I will have to understand the code as I must make sure that there is no regression.